# How do you make a container fill the space left by another?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying for hours but I can't seem to get this right (Sorry i'm not so good in CSS).

My goal is to have a container that will be displayed across the full width of the window's width.

- The parent container has 200px height.

This container has 2 children, which should be placed next to each other in the same line.

- The right container has a fixed width (same as height so 200px).
- The left container's width should be = (current window size - 200px)

I tried using calc like this:

```
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 200px);
```

But it's always gives me a width of -100%

---

Both containers show image carousels, but for the sake of simplicity I'm trying to make it work with a single image.

*Fitting the right image to the right container should be trivial, and i've already managed to make the left image extend to width 100% or height 100% depending on which is smaller. Plus i'm centering the image using Java script.

I thought this could be easily done with CSS but perhaps I need to use Java script as well to recalculate the width every time the size changes?

Here is an image illustrating what I'm trying to accomplish. (https://sketch.io/render/sk-733fbc35d88d981f5b7037c514ab2307.jpeg)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `table` properties for this issue.

This solution is cross browser but `flexbox` and `css calc` aren't.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-div">left</div>
    <div class="right-div">right</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    display: table;
}

.container > div{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.container .right-div{
    width: 200px;
    background: #ddd;
}
.container .left-div{
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/en2qt3L5/3/

Comment: This idea is brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox FTW!

- Set `display` on the parent container to `flex`.
- Set `width` on the left container to `100%`.
- Set `width` on the right container to `200px`.

### Live demo

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.left {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #185218;
}
.right {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #8c1919;
}
.left, .right {
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Variable width</div>
  <div class="right">Fixed width</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use `float: right` on your fixed-width container.
Just ensure that you place the fixed-width container *first*, and then set the `margin-right` of your variable-width container to `200px`.

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/7j8uh0td/

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="fixed-width">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="vari-width">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  color: white
}

.vari-width {
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 200px;
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
}

.fixed-width {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use Flexbox - like @Gothdo has suggested :)

A great website to use for references and examples of CSS (which I still use to this day) is http://learnlayout.com/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Floats are *so* last decade!

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `display` rule of the child elements to `inline-block` and then calculation should work using the `calc` method.

Here is an example.

```css
body { margin: 0; }

.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0;
}

.left, .right {
  display: inline-block;
}

.left {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.right {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: inherit;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```